# Set property on an allocated UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, custom-controls, init

I created a simple UIViewController with a custom init method like this:

```
-(id)initWithGroupNumber:(NSString *)groupNumber {
if ((self = [super init]) == nil) {
    return nil;
}
self.levelGroup = groupNumber;
return self; }
```

levelGroup is a property written in the .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *levelGroup;
```

When I call the method above this way:

```
    LevelsViewController *lvc = [[LevelsViewController alloc]initWithGroupNumber:@"5"];
```

the controller is allocated but all the property inside are set to nil. I can't understand why.

Comment: 1) Unless you're using ARC, `self.levelGroup = [[NSString alloc]init];` creates a memory leak. 2) Didn't you want to do `self.levelGroup = groupNumber;` instead? 3) What do you mean with "all the property inside", there's only one property?

Comment: Also, change the code in your init like this:self = [super init]; if(self) { // Do Stuff } return self;

Comment: @Raphael Ayres: I disagree with your suggestion, there is no need to change this. His solution is absolutely alright. It's semantically correct, so there's no reason to change it. I employ a similar pattern and the advantage is to save an indention level. If find the pattern you suggest (and that Apple uses a lot) ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all when you deal with classes that have subclass of type mutable (e.g. `NSMutableString`), use `copy`.

So, your property should become:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *levelGroup;
```

Then, inside the `UIViewController` synthesize the property

```
@synthesize levelGroup;
```

and in `init` do the following:

```
-(id)initWithGroupNumber:(NSString *)groupNumber {

    if (self = [super init]) {
       levelGroup = [groupNumber copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As written in the [memory management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) you should not use `self.` inside `init` and in `dealloc`.

Use your property `self.levelGroup` to get or set the value.

Remember to release in dealloc:

```
[levelGroup release];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your

```
self.levelGroup = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

with

```
self.levelGroup = groupNumber; // actually uses your init value.
```

Comment: my bad, it was a previous try I forgot. Unfortunately the code still not work even replacing with self.levelGroup = groupNumber..

Comment: @Lolloz89: did you '@synthesize' groupNumber?

Comment: @rokjarc, synthesize `levelGroup`, not `groupNumber`

Comment: Yep. Thank to flex_addicted I found my solution :) Thank you anyway